# Path dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

Here is two targets in my Makefile.

```
.SECONDARY: 
exp-%.ans: 
    echo $* > eval/$@

%.scores: %.ans
    cat eval/$< > eval/$@
```

When I write `make -n exp-40.scores` output would be:

```
echo 40 > eval/exp-40.ans 
cat eval/exp-40.ans > eval/exp-40.scores
```

which is good except one thing. It does not aware of the dependency is already hold. If I create eval/exp-40.scores (first time) then I expect that make will say it is already in there if I run the same command. So I try to change my Makefile like this:

```
.SECONDARY: 
exp-%.ans: 
    echo $* > eval/$@

%.scores: eval/%.ans
    cat eval/$< > $@
```

When I write `make -n exp-40.scores` again and output would be:

```
echo eval/40 > eval/eval/exp-40.ans
cat eval/eval/exp-40.ans > exp-40.scores
```

which is completely wrong because my parameter should be 40 not eval/40.

How can I achieve the best of the these two worlds? Namely, I want to create *.scores in eval/ folder. I also want make to check whether file is already exist or not. Then make should proceed according to that file existence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the core rules of make is that you need to build the target your rule told make that you'd build.  A rule like `foo : bar` tells make that if it runs that recipe, the recipe will create or update a file named `foo`.  If the recipe creates or updates a file named `biz/foo` instead, then your makefile is wrong and things will not work.

Make always puts the target it expects the recipe to create into the `$@` automatic variable.  Your recipe should create or update `$@` and exactly `$@`.  Not something else.

So in your case, you need to write:

```
eval/exp-%.ans: 
        echo $* > $@

eval/%.scores: eval/%.ans
        cat $< > $@
```

If you want to be able to run `make exp-40.scores` and have it actually create `eval/exp-40.scores`, then you can add a rule like this:

```
%.scores: eval/%.scores ; @:
```

(you have to provide some kind of recipe for pattern rules, they cannot have an empty recipe; the one above does nothing).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the clarification at the beginning. I need a tutorial which contains this nature of Makefile. Do you know anything about this? There are lots of short tutorial in web whose aims are usually giving some tips and tricks for doing quick and dirty things. I heard (and I am not sure) the documentation of make is not good and exists lots of bugs. There is an O'Reilly book for Make (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006105.do) but its rating is average.

Comment: If you excuse me, I want to ask two more things. (1) If I remove .SECONDARY, then make deletes my intermediate file which is very important to me in this case. I read (sections for .SECONDARY, .INTERMEDIATE and .PRECIOUS) manual but I don't understand which one is appropriate for this case. (2) And Does .SECONDARY affect all target below it?

Comment: I think the GNU make manual is not bad.  I'm not aware of any bugs in it.  _However_, note that the version of the manual on the GNU website documents the latest stable version of GNU make.  If you are using an older version, then some of the statements in the manual won't be appropriate for your version.  You should read the same version of the manual as the version of GNU make you're using, to avoid confusion.  The manual is packaged with GNU make so you should be able to get the correct docs for your version from the same place you got your make package.

Comment: .SECONDARY is fine.  It applies to _all_ targets in the makefile, regardless of whether they come before or after.

Comment: Thank you for everything :)